# Where is PFFile saved?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I save UIImage as PFFile:

```
let imageFile = PFFile(data: imageData)
imageFile?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({})
```

This file is not referenced with any PFObject, so what happens to him?

1. This file is saved on my reserved storage (20GB)?
2. Is there any tool for clean non-referenced files?
3. If I assign some PFFile to object and replace it by other PFFile after that, first object will be deleted?

Comment: Doesn't sound like you know how parse.com actually works?

Comment: I recently started learning it. And seeking a way to save a user picture. I know that I can upload the file and connect it to the user object, but I wonder what will happen with files that have no connection

Answer (score 0):

PFFile representes a file of binary data stored on the Parse servers. This can be a image, video, or anything else that an application needs to reference in a non-relational way.

Objective-C Code

```
PFQuery *userQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
[userQuery getObjectInBackgroundWithId:user.objectId block:^(PFObject *loginUser, NSError *error) {
    loginUser[@"FBProfilePicture"] = user[@"FBProfilePicture"];
    loginUser[@"FBProfilePicture_Data"] = [PFFile fileWithName:@"image.png" data:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:user[@"FBProfilePicture"]]]];
    [loginUser saveInBackground];
}];
```